# map.containsKey(key) returns true, but map.get(key) doesn't return anything

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on getting a simple messaging system working using Firebase. But this one thing is causing me to want to pull out my own hair. I have a map that I'm using to store `<String,Message>` pairs, where `Message` is a class I wrote. I can't get my messages out of the map though. I've isolated the problem to be with `map.get(key)` not returning the Message, even though `map.containsKey(key)` returns `true`. What could be causing this and how do I fix it?

Here's the Message class:

```
public class Message {
    private long timeStamp;
    private String message;
    private String to;
    private String from;

    public Message(String message, String to, String from)
    {
        timeStamp = new Date().getTime();
        this.message = message;
        this.to = to;
        this.from = from;
    }

    public Message(){

    }

    public String getMessageText() {
        return this.message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getTo() {
        return this.to; 
    }

    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public String getFrom() {
        return this.from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public long getTimeStamp() {
        return this.timeStamp;
    }

    public void setTimeStamp(long timeStamp) { 
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp; 
    }
}
```

This is the code I used that showed me `map.containsKey(key)` returns `true`:

```
public class LoadMessages extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_messages);

    // Load previous messages

    final LinearLayout messagesLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.messagesLayout);

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = database.getReference(getIntent().getStringExtra("user") + "/Messages");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Map<String, Message> map = new TreeMap<String, Message>();

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Message m = snapshot.getValue(Message.class);
                map.put(String.valueOf(m.getTimeStamp()), m);

                TextView TV = new TextView(LoadMessages.this);
                Boolean ck = map.containsKey(String.valueOf(m.getTimeStamp()));
                if (ck) {
                    TV.setText("Contains key");
                } else {
                    TV.setText("Doesn't contain key.");
                }
                messagesLayout.addView(TV);
            }

            // code to iterate through map entries and display messages

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    // code Add new message onClick of fab

}
}
```

And this version of the code shows nothing in the `TextView`:

```
public class LoadMessages extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_messages);

    // Load previous messages

    final LinearLayout messagesLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.messagesLayout);

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = database.getReference(getIntent().getStringExtra("user") + "/Messages");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Map<String, Message> map = new TreeMap<String, Message>();

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Message m = snapshot.getValue(Message.class);
                map.put(String.valueOf(m.getTimeStamp()), m);

                TextView TV = new TextView(LoadMessages.this);
                Message test = map.get(String.valueOf(m.getTimeStamp()));
                TV.setText(test.getMessageText());
                messagesLayout.addView(TV);
            }

            // code to iterate through map entries and display messages

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    // code Add new message onClick of fab

}
}
```

Edit: Here's my database structure:
[image]

Comment: I would comment but I don't have 50 rep apparently. Quick question, why are you using String.valueOf(m.getTimeStamp()) rather than just using something like - ? m.getTimeStamp() + ""

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out! It turns out that the message String in Message was being changed to messageText in the database, so when I tried to extract it into a Message object it wouldn't recognize it. The fix was to change the message String in the Message class to messageText.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `snapshot.getValue(Message.class)` returns null.
TreeMap can store null as a value, so while it contains your key the value is actually null.

Comment: I was able to get the correct time stamp from m (which is instantiated with snapshot.getValue(Message.class)), so I don't think this is the case. Still can't figure this out...

Comment: Did you try to break right after you insert the new value into the map and see what the map contains at that point?